# I tried with this to avoid string and special character in textfield. I try this but project get crashed

Tags: ios

```
let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn:
   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&-+=%*1234567890"
)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

//here is my multiply action button action
@IBAction func actionMultiplyAns(sender:UIButton) {

```
    if txtFldOne.text == "" && txtFldTwo.text == "" && txtFldThree.text == ""{
        alert(Title: "No Input", Message: "Kindly Enter SomeInput")
    }
    else if ((txtFldOne.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) && ((txtFldTwo.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) && ((txtFldThree.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
    else if ((txtFldOne.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) &&   txtFldTwo.text != "" && txtFldThree.text != "" {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
    else if txtFldOne.text != "" &&   ((txtFldTwo.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) && txtFldThree.text != "" {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
    else if txtFldOne.text != "" &&    txtFldTwo.text != "" && ((txtFldThree.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
```

Comment: What crash you are getting, can you provide some information from logs?

Comment: when i write character both string and integers combine , then it get crashed. I want  only Int value , if any string value occur , then it should show alert

Comment: Speedy is asking you to post the error message you get and what line fo code caused the issue. Please edit your question and provide the necessary details. Don't provide an answer to your own question to add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn:
"0123456789"
)
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
//here is my multiply action button action
@IBAction func actionMultiplyAns(sender:UIButton) {

```
    if txtFldOne.text == "" && txtFldTwo.text == "" && txtFldThree.text == ""{
        alert(Title: "No Input", Message: "Kindly Enter SomeInput")
    }
    else if ((txtFldOne.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) && ((txtFldTwo.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) && ((txtFldThree.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
    else if ((txtFldOne.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) &&   txtFldTwo.text != "" && txtFldThree.text != "" {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
    else if txtFldOne.text != "" &&   ((txtFldTwo.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) && txtFldThree.text != "" {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
    else if txtFldOne.text != "" &&    txtFldTwo.text != "" && ((txtFldThree.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted)) != nil) {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs")
    }
  

    else if txtFldOne.text == "" && txtFldTwo.text != "" && txtFldThree.text != ""{
        alert(Title: "No Input In First Block", Message: "Kindly Enter Some Input In First Block")
    }
    else if txtFldOne.text != "" && txtFldTwo.text == "" &&  txtFldThree.text != "" {
        alert(Title: "No Input In Second Block", Message: "Kindly Enter Some Input In Second Block")
    }
    else if txtFldOne.text != "" && txtFldTwo.text == "" &&  txtFldThree.text == "" {
        alert(Title: "No Input In Second Block", Message: "Kindly Enter Some Input In Second Block")
    }
    else if txtFldOne.text != "" && txtFldTwo.text != "" &&  txtFldThree.text == "" {
        alert(Title: "No Input In Third Block", Message: "Kindly Enter Some Input In Third Block")
    }
    else {
        var firstNumber = Int(txtFldOne.text!)
        var secondNumber = Int(txtFldTwo.text!)
        var thirdNumber  = Int(txtFldThree.text!)

        var ans = Int(firstNumber! * secondNumber! * thirdNumber!)
        
        lblDisply.text = "\(ans)" }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is your logic -- you are using `&&`, meaning you are checking that **all three** match the conditions:

```
if txtFldOne.text == "" && txtFldTwo.text == "" && txtFldThree.text == ""
```

So you are saying "Only match if ALL THREE fields are empty."

Instead, you should use logical OR `||`:

```
if txtFldOne.text == "" || txtFldTwo.text == "" || txtFldThree.text == ""
```

Now we're saying "If first field is empty OR second field is empty OR third field is empty."

Second, you should study how to properly / safely **unwrap** optional values.

Here's a modified version of your `actionMultiplyAns` function:

```
@IBAction func actionMultiplyAns(sender:UIButton) {
    
    // unwrap optional .text property of each field
    //  and make sure its not empty ""
    guard let txt1 = txtFldOne.text, !txt1.isEmpty
    else {
        alert(Title: "No Input In First Block", Message: "Kindly Enter Some Input In First Block")
        return
    }
    
    guard let txt2 = txtFldTwo.text, !txt2.isEmpty
    else {
        alert(Title: "No Input In Second Block", Message: "Kindly Enter Some Input In Second Block")
        return
    }
    
    guard let txt3 = txtFldThree.text, !txt3.isEmpty
    else {
        alert(Title: "No Input In Third Block", Message: "Kindly Enter Some Input In Third Block")
        return
    }

    // validate text entries contain only Numbers
    if txt1.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) != nil {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs in First Block")
        return
    }
    if txt2.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) != nil {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs in Second Block")
        return
    }
    if txt3.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) != nil {
        alert(Title: "Use Numbers", Message: "Kindly Enter Numberic Inputs in Third Block")
        return
    }

    // properly unwrap optionals
    guard let firstNumber  = Int(txt1),
          let secondNumber = Int(txt2),
          let thirdNumber  = Int(txt3)
    else {
        alert(Title: "Error", Message: "Could not convert text entries to Integers")
        return
    }

    let ans = firstNumber * secondNumber * thirdNumber
        
    lblDisply.text = "\(ans)" }
    
}
```